# $(window).ready(function() ){} should wait for images,css to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am using the `_fitScreen` function which fits my UI in a particular window. I am calling `_fitScreen` function from `$(window).load()`. However `window.load()` will execute only when page gets fully loaded i.e if I press CTRL+F5. I want to execute `_fitScreen` when I switch between tabs.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  me._fitScreen();
});
```

I know I can use `$(window).ready(function() {})`, but `ready()` will not wait for images or CSS to be loaded.

Can anyone suggest me how can use `ready()` to wait for images and CSS to load? I don't want to use third party plugin.

Comment: have you tried `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Do you have some kind of a SPA page?

Comment: Not exactly SPA page. One page of whole web application

Comment: *switch between tabs.* You can try `$(window).on('focus load', function(){...})`

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.ready` won't fix anything. The fact it runs before CSS and images are loaded is irrelevant to the issue.

Given that the problem is that you want to resize the UI when the tab is refocused (presumably in case the window was resized while the tab holding your site wasn't active) then you simply need to hook to the `resize` event.

You could use other techniques to know when the tab loses/gets focus, but again they are not relevant given the problem statement above. Try this:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  me._fitScreen();
});
```

You should also note that relying on JS to fix your UI based on screen size is a *monumentally bad idea*. Use CSS Media queries instead, and avoid this issue completely.